# Python: Plotting curved-arrows around the circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here I am trying to make curved arrows around a circle. Found out that I can use `Fancyarrows` to do it. But the below code is not producing the required result. I want a curved arrow around the circle. But my code is intersecting the circle, not drawing around it. Here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.set(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))

circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 6)
ax.add_patch(circle)

a = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 6.5), (6.5, 0),
                             connectionstyle="arc3,rad=.5", **kw)
ax.add_patch(a)
plt.show()
```

Output is:

[image]

What changes should I do in my code so that I can get the desired result?

Comment: To curve the other way you can make `rad` negative